# How do I make my flex cell fill up its whole space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Whenever I hover over the box, the cell's background takes up the full width (thanks to the `width: 100%`) but when I do the same with height, it doesn't do so. The parent doesn't have any padding, so how can I fix this?

I have looked at links like "https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/" and tried using `flex-grow` but it doesn't seem to work for me, but I am probably messing it up.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

div p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div p:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Header1</p>
  <p>Header2</p>
  <p>Header3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `margin:0` on the `p`, By default the `p` tag has margin which what you're seeing as height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paragraph elements have a default margin set on them.

[image]

You need to disable those and, instead, give a height to the container.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

div p {
  margin: 0;      /* override default margins */
  flex: 1;        /* consume full width */
  display: flex;  /* for aligning content of flex item */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div p:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Header1</p>
  <p>Header2</p>
  <p>Header3</p>
</div>
```

Understanding "block start":

- "block-start" is the top in horizontal writing mode.
- "inline-start" is the side where text begins. It's the left side in LTR.
- "-end" refers to the opposite side.
- source: [§ 6.2. Flow-relative Directions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/#logical-directions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *span* tag instead of *p* and provide padding to it as below;

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

div span {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
}

div span:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Header1</span>
  <span>Header2</span>
  <span>Header3</span>
</div>
```